# Filling missing values based on multi-column subgroup

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, pandas-groupby

I want to fill missing "Age" values of a DataFrame by a mean of a two-column subgroup.

```
df.groupby(["col_x","col_y"])["Age"].mean()
```

The code above returns the means of these sub-groups:

```
col_X   col_Y
X       1         35
        2         29
        3         22
Y       1         41
        2         31
        3         27
```

I have a feeling this can be achieved by using the .map function:

```
df.loc[df['Age'].isnull(),'Age'] = df[['col_X',"col_Y"]].map(something)
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's better with `groupby().transform`, which returns a series with same index as `df`. So you can `fillna` with it:

```
df['Age'] = df['Age'].fillna(df.groupby(['col_x','col_y'])['Age'].transform('mean'))
```